# Enum structure creation

Tags: swift, enums, protocols, swift3

I'm working on a model definition with Swift 3.
I have two simple enum :

```
enum CompanyField: String {
    case id
    case name
}

enum UserField: String {
    case email
    case id
    case id_company
}
```

When using collections I would to like to conform to a generic type. Something like `Field` e.g:

```
let fields: [Field : String] = [UserField.id : "1", CompanyField.name : "A name"]
```

or

```
let fields: [Field] = [UserField.id, CompanyField.name]
```

I was trying to create a Field protocol but without success. (e.g: `enum UserField: Field {}`)

Is there any solution to have my two enum conforming to one single custom type ?

Comment: *...without success* don't tell much about the real issue, what's your concern ?

Comment: @xhamr I would like to know how to achieve this structure but I don't know if using a protocol is correct. If so, I have a Hashable compile error for the protocol. I tried to make it conforming to Hashable but getting other errors.

Comment: The issue is that `Equatable` protocol which is conformed by `Hashable` has`Self` associated and can't be used as type declarator. you can go with a workaround of wrapping the map creation in a generic function but that still avoid to mix different enum types in the same map.

Comment: I posted an answer to you see what I mean, and maybe give you some idea of what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

This can give you a flexible way to express you enums conform a custom domain protocol and still be used as dictionary and array elements. *but again, this avoid to mix different enum types as dict key*:

```
func map<K,V>(forFields fields: (K,V)...) -> [K:V] where K : Hashable{
    var dict = [K:V]()
    fields.forEach { (key, value) in
       dict[key as K] = value
    }
    return dict
}
map(forFields: (UserField.email, "email"), (UserField.id,"id"))
```